# How can I update a wxStaticBitamp?

Tags: python, wxpython

**[PROBLEM]**
I want to update the wxStaticBitamp image if the user clicks on some item from wx.TreeCtrl.

**[CODE]**

```python
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

def createHelpWindow(event):
    import wx  
    locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, " Help contents", style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX) # A Frame is a top-level window.
    frame.Center()
    frame.SetBackgroundColour('LIGHTGREY')
    frame.SetSize(800,600)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

    # Add control tree
    treeHelp = wx.TreeCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE )
    sizer.Add(treeHelp,(1,1),(19,23),wx.EXPAND)

    # Add description box
    helpDisplay = wx.StaticText( frame, wx.ID_ANY, "", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0, )
    sizer.Add(helpDisplay,(1,26),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)

    # Create image object
    chooseMessageImage = wx.StaticBitmap( frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(wx.NullBitmap), wx.Point( 300,110 ),wx.DefaultSize, 0)
    def OnSelChanged(event):
        locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
        chooseMessageImage = wx.StaticBitmap( frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(wx.NullBitmap), wx.Point( 300,110 ),wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        item =  event.GetItem()

        # Display the selected item text in the text widget
        print "selected ", treeHelp.GetItemText(item)
        if treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'TFT':
            helpSecondDisplay.SetLabel("""test page for landing page""")
            chooseMessageImage.SetBitmap(wx.NullBitmap) # Set image object to null
        #################### End main #########################
        elif treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'Main page':
            helpSecondDisplay.SetLabel("""test txt for main page""")
            chooseMessageImage.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap( u"create_images/add_message.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)) # Set image to some src  
    treeHelp.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, OnSelChanged)
    helpSecondDisplay = wx.StaticText( frame, wx.ID_ANY, "Lorem ipsum", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0, )
    sizer.Add(helpSecondDisplay,(3,26),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)   
    root = treeHelp.AddRoot('TFT')
    rootMainPage = treeHelp.AppendItem(root, 'Main page') 
    treeHelp.Expand(root)

    # Wrap it up
    frame.SetSizer(sizer)
    frame.Center()    
    frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.


# Bind the method
helpButton = wx.Button(top, wx.ID_ANY, u"help",  style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(helpButton,(0,0),(1,1))
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, createHelpWindow, helpButton)  
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

**[CURRENT]**
The image object (chooseMessageImage) is shown when I click on root.

**[DESIRED]**
The image object (chooseMessageImage) should not shown when I click on root.

note: when the window is loaded, the focus will be set on root but the image will not be displayed.

EDIT 1:

```
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

def createHelpWindow(event):
    import wx  
    locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, " Help contents", style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX) # A Frame is a top-level window.
    frame.Center()
    frame.SetBackgroundColour('LIGHTGREY')
    frame.SetSize(800,600)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

    # Add control tree
    treeHelp = wx.TreeCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE )
    sizer.Add(treeHelp,(1,1),(19,23),wx.EXPAND)

    # Add description box
    helpDisplay = wx.StaticText( frame, wx.ID_ANY, "", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0, )
    sizer.Add(helpDisplay,(1,26),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)

    # Create image object
    chooseMessageImage = wx.StaticBitmap( frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap, wx.Point( 300,110 ),wx.DefaultSize, 0)
    def OnSelChanged(event):
        locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
        chooseMessageImage = wx.StaticBitmap( frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap, wx.Point( 300,110 ),wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        item =  event.GetItem()

        # Display the selected item text in the text widget
        print "selected ", treeHelp.GetItemText(item)
        if treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'TFT':
            helpSecondDisplay.SetLabel("""test page for landing page""")
            chooseMessageImage.SetBitmap(wx.NullBitmap) # Set image object to null
        #################### End main #########################
        elif treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'Main page':
            helpSecondDisplay.SetLabel("""test txt for main page""")
            chooseMessageImage.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap( "create_images/add_message.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)) # Set image to some src
        chooseMessageImage.Refresh()
    treeHelp.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, OnSelChanged)
    helpSecondDisplay = wx.StaticText( frame, wx.ID_ANY, "Lorem ipsum", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0, )
    sizer.Add(helpSecondDisplay,(3,26),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)   
    root = treeHelp.AddRoot('TFT')
    rootMainPage = treeHelp.AppendItem(root, 'Main page') 
    treeHelp.Expand(root)

    # Wrap it up
    frame.SetSizer(sizer)
    frame.Center()    
    frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.


# Bind the method
helpButton = wx.Button(top, wx.ID_ANY, u"help",  style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(helpButton,(0,0),(1,1))
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, createHelpWindow, helpButton)  
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: there's quite a few problems with your sample code. wx.Bitmap(wx.NullBitmap) raises a TypeError and you reference an image "add_message.png" that we obviously won't have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. The final working code is:

```
import wx


app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

def createHelpWindow(event):
    import wx
    locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, " Help contents", style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX) # A Frame is a top-level window.
    frame.Center()
    frame.SetBackgroundColour('LIGHTGREY')
    frame.SetSize(800,600)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
    # Add control tree
    treeHelp = wx.TreeCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE )
    sizer.Add(treeHelp,(1,1),(19,23),wx.EXPAND)
    # Add description box
    helpDisplay = wx.StaticText( frame, wx.ID_ANY, "", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0, )
    sizer.Add(helpDisplay,(1,26),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)
    # Create image object
    chooseMessageImage = wx.StaticBitmap( frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap, wx.Point( 300,110 ),wx.DefaultSize, 0)
    def OnSelChanged(event):
        locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
        item =  event.GetItem()
        # Display the selected item text in the text widget
        print "selected ", treeHelp.GetItemText(item)
        if treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'TFT':
            helpSecondDisplay.SetLabel("""test page for landing page""")
            chooseMessageImage.SetBitmap(wx.NullBitmap) # Set image object to null
        #################### End main #########################
        elif treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'Main page':
            helpSecondDisplay.SetLabel("""test txt for main page""")
            chooseMessageImage.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap( "create_images/add_message.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)) # Set image to some src
            frame.Refresh()
    treeHelp.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, OnSelChanged)
    helpSecondDisplay = wx.StaticText( frame, wx.ID_ANY, "Lorem ipsum", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0, )
    sizer.Add(helpSecondDisplay,(3,26),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)
    root = treeHelp.AddRoot('TFT')
    rootMainPage = treeHelp.AppendItem(root, 'Main page')
    treeHelp.Expand(root)
    # Wrap it up
    frame.SetSizer(sizer)
    frame.Center()
    frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.


# Bind the method
helpButton = wx.Button(top, wx.ID_ANY, u"help",  style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(helpButton,(0,0),(1,1))
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, createHelpWindow, helpButton)
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

My mistake was that I created the bitmapObj inside OnSelChanged method.

Answer (score 3):

add a Refresh() call after changing the image

```
#################### End main #########################
elif treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'Main page':
    helpSecondDisplay.SetLabel("""test txt for main page""")
    chooseMessageImage.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap( "create_images/add_message.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)) # Set image to some src
chooseMessageImage.Refresh()
```

and change `wx.Bitmap(wx.NullBitmap)` to just `wx.NullBitmap`

from the wxpython docs about Refresh():

> ```
>     """
>     Refresh(self, bool eraseBackground=True, Rect rect=None)
>
>     Mark the specified rectangle (or the whole window) as "dirty" so it
>     will be repainted.  Causes an EVT_PAINT event to be generated and sent
>     to the window.
>     """
> ```

Comment: I've tried your approach. I have pefromed the 2 changes that you've suggested, but the image object (chooseMessageImage) is still shown when I click on root. (if treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'TFT':). still investigating...

Comment: Weird. It's working for me. Instead of chooseMessageImage.Refresh() try frame.Refresh()

Comment: yes. I agree. I tried also Update() and Destroy(), but to no avail. the exact code that I am running now can be found on Edit 1. could it be related to wxpython version?

Comment: Yeah possible. I'm running it on windows 10, Python 2.7.10 and the latest stable wxpython. I'll run it again in a bit.

Comment: I am running on python: 2.7.10 + wxpython: 3.0.3.dev1830+0b5f910

Comment: No. because, so far, this is the only problem that I've encountered. I'll try changing wxpython version...

Comment: Maybe try that. You can have multiple versions installed and select the version you want to use by importing wxversion and calling wxversion.select("2.9")

Comment: I have tried with: wxpython version.3.0.2.0. still if I click on root (if treeHelp.GetItemText(item) == 'TFT':) I will see the image. i'll keep trying ..